# Nature of open set in a metric space.

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space such that  $\text{card} (X)\geq 2$ and $d(x, y)\in \mathbb{N}$, then which of the following are correct,

1) Every open set in $(X, d)$ is infinite.

2) Every sequence in $(X, d)$ is convergent.

3) Every singleton in $(X, d)$ is open.

4) Every singleton in $(X, d)$ is closed.

My intuition says 3 and 4 are correct. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

1) is wrong because $\{a\}=B_{1}(a)$ for any $a\in X$.

2) is wrong because $(x_{n})=(a,b,a,b,a,b,...)$, where $a\ne b$, $a,b\in X$ is not convergent since $d(x_{n+1},x_{n})\geq 1$.

3) is correct as in the reasoning in 1).

4) is correct because $X$ is $T_{1}$.

Comment: I got your point, but I want to ask that in answer (1) your $d(x, y)$ is zero which is not in the OP given set.

Comment: But as a part of the definition of metric $d$, one must have $d(x,x)=0$.

Comment: @1256 That particular definition of $\mathbb{N}$ must include $0$.